# Google Analytics Measurement Protocol hit appears in Realtime But not in Behavior section

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

We are currently implementing event delivery using the measurement protocol. We have observed that when we send a "ScreenView" type event with the url:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?t=screenview&cd=XXX - Screensaver&an=POK&av=DEV - 4.43&v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-2&cid=7E1C6CB8-966B-4219-A547-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

In the request we replaced the sensitive info with XXX... and decoded the url to show the spaces.

This is sent, we receive a Http - 200 and appears on the screen Realtime / Screens but after several days, more than 48 hours, these requests do not see in Behavior / Screens.

We have read the documentation, and the forum but we don't know why it happens.

Comment: did you disable filter bots in the admin section?

Comment: Yes, the bot filter is disabled in the admin section.

Comment: is it a mobile google analytics account or a web google analytics account?

Comment: I tried to send your measurement protocol on my own analytics app property and the data are visible in the behavior section. So, either you are not using an app property or there are filters (but you said no).

Comment: As an aside, for the measurement protocol, a http 200 status just says that the server is still there. It does not mean tracking has been successful (so it's basically useless for debugging).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the account with which the events were counted in the panel of realtime but not of behavior was a Google Analytics account that was configured to receive events of a mobile application of Ios. We created a web type account and tried to change the events and instead of sending them as screenview we sent them as pageview and everything counts perfectly in the behavior section. In my opinion I think google should clarify that the measurement protocol no longer works with mobile accounts.